# PHP - convert little endian hex to big endian hex

Tags: php, byte, endianness, pack, unpack

I am trying to convert **little endian** hex to **big endian** hex.

Example:

Little endian: 
`E1 31 01 00 00 9D`

Big endian:
`9D 00 00 01 31 E1`

Comment: Have been trying several things with pack and unpack, didn't get anywhere at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If numbers are in the format described than you can convert by using standard array functions.

```
function littleToBigEndian($little) {
  return implode(' ',array_reverse(explode(' ', $little)));
}

echo littleToBigEndian('E1 31 3C 01 00 00 9B');
// Output: 9B 00 00 01 3C 31 E1
```

If there are no spaces for separation of numbers you need to `str_split()` the string instead.

```
function littleToBigEndian($little) {
  return implode('',array_reverse(str_split($little,2)));
}

echo littleToBigEndian('E1313C0100009B');
// Output: 9B0000013C31E1
```

Comment: Simple and beautiful implementation. I used to build a bigToLittleEndian function, the code is the same, just needed to switch the names.

Answer (score 0):

To change endianness for an hexadecimal string that could contain spaces, I would use the following code.

```php
function change_endianness(string $input): string {
  $input = str_replace(' ', '', $input);
  $output = unpack("H*", strrev(pack("H*", $input)))[1];
  // Add a space every two hexadecimal digits.
  $output = implode(' ', str_split($output, 2));
  // Convert lowercase hexadecimal digits to uppercase.
  return strtoupper($output);
}
```

```
echo change_endianness('E1 31 3C 01 00 00 9B'), "\n";
9B 00 00 01 3C 31 E1
```